# how to get the response time of web pages in jmeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

How to generte csv file and load csv using response time graph listener?

Can any one help me in detail that **how we find response time in jmeter** ?

Comment: What is the consistency of match witht the question in the Title and the Description? Title is a different question, Description is another question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it by adding Reporters.

Please keep in mind Reporters is cpu and memory intensive components and thus should not be used while actual load test.

But for sample testing you can use it and for load test run you can get response time, average,throughput etc by saving output to jtl file in JMeter.

For normal/sample run

Aggregate report gives Average response time, min, max, median etc.

[image]

Summary report also gives the same with less details,

[image]

While performing actual run you can save output of these reporters in a jtl file. After the test results can be analyzed from jtl files.

Comment: Load time returns in milliseconds or in seconds?

Answer (score 7):

If you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) as follows:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test_plan.jmx -l /path/to/results_file.jtl
```

your `results_file.jtl` content will look like:

> 1409124780902,**182**,Logon,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,214,0
>   1409124781219,**153**,Logout,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,110,0

where second column is page response time in milliseconds.

Other values are:

- "1409124780902" - current time stamp in ms
- "182" - page response time
- "Logon" - sampler name
- "200" - Response Code
- "OK" - Response Message
- "Thread Group 1-1" - Parent Thread Group name, thread number and iteration.
- "text" - response data type
- "214" - response data size in bytes
- "0" - latency

Once your test run is done you can open JMeter GUI and load this `results_file.jtl` into the listener of your choice.

You might also be interested in [JMeter Plugins Extras Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasSet/) which is capable of generating nice looking and easy understandable response-time related graphs to wit:

- [Response Times vs Threads](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads)
- [Response Times Distribution](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RespTimesDistribution/)
- [Response Times Percentiles](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RespTimePercentiles)